# Why is my Vue+Vite project not showing in the web browser?

Tags: docker, frontend, vuejs3, vite

I am almost a newborn in Docker. I am trying to setup a basic structure for me with Django in the API, Vue+Vite in the frontend and Postgres as a DB.
All these three run perfectly when I run them locally and not using the docker-compose. But in the case of the frontend side, it runs and shows but when I run the Dockerfile or the docker-compose it doesn't work. I have looked at some posts, but I can't find what seems to be the problem.

I have tried running it locally, then using Dockerfile and the docker-compose file too.

As you can see it shows no error and it works in the browser:
[image: npm run locally]
[image: npm run locally on the browser]

and then the docker-compose execution:

[image: docker-compose execution]

it doesn't run on the 8080 port either, I know that's the one I'm exporting in the docker-compose file.
[image: web browser after docker execution]

This is my frontend Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18.12.0

WORKDIR /frontend

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm ci

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5173
CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

  web:
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - "5173:8080"

  api:
    build: ./backend
    volumes:
      - .:/home/myuser
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there were two errors in my code. First and simplest, my web export ports were wrong, they should be `- "8080:5173"`. With that fixed, it was still not working, so I added this line to the Dockerfile:

`CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev", "--host 0.0.0.0" ]`

That just did it for me. Now it's working. I hope this helps someone else.

I want to state that this is only for development environment, not for production.